# (Codewars) Linked Lists - Remove Duplicates

Tags: python, performance, beginner, programming-challenge, linked-list

Kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/linked-lists-remove-duplicates/train/python

### Description

> Write a RemoveDuplicates() function which takes a list sorted in increasing order and deletes any duplicate nodes from the list. Ideally, the list should only be traversed once. The head of the resulting list should be returned.
>
> ```
> var list = 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
> removeDuplicates(list) === 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
> ```
>
> If the passed in list is null/None/nil, simply return null.
>
> Note: Your solution is expected to work on long lists. Recursive solutions may fail due to stack size limitations.

### My Solution

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, nxt=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = nxt

def remove_duplicates(head):
    node = Node(None, head)
    st = set()
    while node.next:
        if node.next.data in st:
            tmp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            del tmp
        else:
            st.add(node.next.data)
            node = node.next
    return head
```

---

I am interested in performance and adhering to best practices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space complexity of your solution is \$O(n)\$. What if I told you that given the constraints in the question, you could solve this problem in \$O(1)\$ space?

Consider that you receive an already sorted list. This implies that all duplicates **must be** adjacent. This in turn means that for deduplicating these, you do not need to keep track of which values you already encountered.

Note that `del` is not necessary here. You never use `tmp` aside from assigning `node.next` to it in any case. `del` is not clearing the memory allocated to the variable (or the object it refers to), it only destroys the variable itself, the object is unaffected. As such it does *not* have any effect on the garbage-collection that python performs...

The following should already work just fine:

```py
def remove_duplicates(head):
    node = Node(None, head)
    while node.next:
        if node.next.data == node.data:
            node.next = node.next.next
        else:
            node = node.next
    return head
```

---

Small sidenote: I really like the hack you used to ensure that you handle the `head is None` case, but you should be aware that it is just a hack. The cleaner solution to this would be:

```py
def remove_duplicates(head):
    if not head:
        return head
    node = head
    while node.next:
        # Rest of the code...
```

Comment: Surely `if head is None` would be better than `if not head`, no? It may or may not be faster, depending on where the bottlenecks are (it's usually faster) _and_ it more clearly conveys the intent of the code.

Comment: Thanks for this, yours is really neat. It still looks like it's \$O(n)\$ to me as you have to iterate through the list?

Comment: I find special cases aesthetically unappealing which is why I used the "hack"; is that considered bad form?

Comment: it is in fact O(n) in **time**, but O(1) in **space**. Special cases are something I prefer to handle "separately". YMMV, but as soon as special cases become harder to reconciliate with the core algorithm, it makes more and more sense to handle them in dedicated branches